# Orbiting around axis at an angle

Tags: animation, transforms

As you know, Earth rotates around it's axis in an angle of 23.5 degrees. How do I make a sphere in Blender rotate like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the sphere's y-axis to 23.5 and *[Rotation Mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Pepribal/Ref/Appendices/Rotation)* to *ZYX Euler*. After that you can rotate the sphere around its local z-axis.

Set a keyframe with <kbd>I</kbd> at frame 1 add another one at e.g. frame 240 with z-rotation set to 359.

[image]

See also:

- [Manual Rotation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Basics/Rotate)

Comment: No need to use 359; if you type it in manually, you can use 360 just fine (or anything greater for that matter).

Comment: And set the interpolation for both keyframes to linear

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options

- Use axis-angle rotation mode
  *(a direct answer to your question)*.
- Set the euler-rotation order so Z is applied last.
- Use an empty parent, for the tilt and simply animate the child meshes Z axis.
  *(I'd do this, it generally gives more control so the spin and the tilt independently)*.
- You could use **Copy Rotation** constraint, but I don't think theres much advantage to this.

Answer (score 0):

angular velocity in Blender is not constant. To make it constant, go to Graph Editor select the animation, in the graph select the start an end and press V and change it to vector. This is in a nutshell. look for a tutorial for the Graph Editor